# Redirect to the same page on application error in mvc .net

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am working in MVC2 .net and getting problem on file upload. If file size exceeds form the limit then i want to show some exception on the same page.

Comment: Hi, maybe this post can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3007737/how-can-i-handle-maxrequestlength-exceptions-elegantly

Answer (score 2):

In the past I have created an Image Size Attribute and used data annotations to validate images.

```
public sealed class ImageSizeAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }

    private const string DefaultErrorMessage = "{0} dimensions cannot be greater than {1} x {2}";

    public ImageSizeAttribute(int width, int height)
        : base(DefaultErrorMessage)
    {
        Width = width;
        Height = height;
    }

    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        return string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, ErrorMessageString, name, Width, Height);
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        // Turn HttpPostedFileBase into Image and validate size...
    }
}
```

In your view model you can now just add an attribute to validate it.

```
[ImageSize(200, 200)]
public HttpPostedFileBase Avatar { get; set; }
```

In your view make sure you at least have a validation message

```
<%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.Avatar) %>
```

and you can read this post about [enabling client validation](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/15/asp-net-mvc-2-model-validation.aspx)

Now in your controller you can do your validation and if something goes wrong just return the same view with the existing model and you will see the error messages.

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    // More validation and saving.
    ...
    return RedirectToRoute("UserDetails", ...);
}
return View(model);
```